# Accent in Russian above «ы» goes to next line

Tags: hyphenation, russian

I am trying to typeset a document in Russian with huge amount of accents, almost in every word. They are typeset by U+0301, «combining acute accent». And I get a problem that in some cases the accent goes to the next line:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont[Mapping=tex-text]{PT Serif}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont

\hyphenation{ны́-не}

\begin{document}
\parbox{1pt}{Почему́ перено́сы в словах ны́не и мы́ши ухо́дят на сле́дующую стро́чку, а в мя́со брэ́кет слу́хи ворю́га — нет?}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Even the `\hyphenation` does not help.

Making `\'ы` also does not help.

Making `\mbox{ы́}` kills the hyphenation in the word.

How can I fix it without going through the whole text (it's Psalter, by the way) and putting full hyphenation pattern inside the words, like `ны́\-не`?

Comment: I suspect an issue in the hyphenation patterns; it is not font dependent, because the same happens with Old Standard and Libertinus Serif.

Comment: @egreg How can I fix it? Where to look at, I never worked with the hyphenation patterns.

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but don't load \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} when using xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: Btw: with luatex the \hyphenation works.

Comment: @pantlmn You might ask at http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-hyphen

Comment: What file is responsible for the hyphenation patterns?

Is it  /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-ru.tex ?

It contains line 4255:

ы1

which means that any word can have a hyphen after «ы».

Do I understand it right?

But deleting this line does not help :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the help from [tex-hyphen mailing list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-hyphen), especially from Claudio Beccari, the solution is like this.

The file `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-ru.tex` contained the line `ы1` which means that any word can have hyphen right after «ы». No other vowel had such a pattern (and thus they did not produce such errors).

So there are two solutions:

1. Add `2^^^^0301` or `4^^^^0301` or `8^^^^0301` into the `hyph-ru.tex`. It means «forbid hyphenation before combining acute accent». The greater is the number, the stronger is the ban.
2. Remove `ы1` from `hyph-ru.tex`. It means «„ы“ is not a letter after which you can hyphenate in any case, look at other patterns».

After editing you should run `fmtutil --all` (or `fmtutil-sys --all` or maybe the option should be `--byhyphen ...`, I do not really understand it, but `fmtutil --all` worked for me OK. It shouldn't be `sudo fmtutil`!).

**[Added Jan 25, 2019]:**
To avoid hyphenation of *one letter with accent* you can add these lines to `hyph-ru.tex`:

```
8^^^^0301
8а^^^^0301.
8е^^^^0301.
8и^^^^0301.
8о^^^^0301.
8у^^^^0301.
8ы^^^^0301.
8э^^^^0301.
8ю^^^^0301.
8я^^^^0301.
.а^^^^03018
.е^^^^03018
.и^^^^03018
.о^^^^03018
.у^^^^03018
.ы^^^^03018
.э^^^^03018
.ю^^^^03018
.я^^^^03018
```